# Any way to allow user to change line height in Kendo UI Web editor

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there any way to add a button to the toolbar in Kendo UI web editor that allows user to change line height of the selected content?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you are referring to is accomplished by configuring the `stylesheets` property of the editor, and then configuring the tools that will apply the styles to the selected content.

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
  tools: [
    { name: "formatting", items: [
      { text: "Highlight Error", value: ".hlError" },
      { text: "Highlight OK", value: ".hlOK" },
      { text: "Inline Code", value: ".inlineCode" }
    ] }
  ],
  stylesheets: [
    "../../content/web/editor/editorStyles.css"
  ]
});
```

Please refer to this demo on Kendo UI's site: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/styles.html.